# Definite integral over a vector field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, notation, integration, vector-fields

This article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#Path_independence) showed that if the force field is conservative, then the work done on a mass between $t_1$ and $t_2$ is $$\int_{\vec{x}(t_1)}^{\vec{x}(t_2)} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x} $$
where $\vec{x}(t_1)$ and $\vec{x}(t_2)$ are the start and end positions of the curve respectively.

Since it dropped the notion of a line integral and used a definite integral instead, what does this integral actually mean? (What is the definition of a definite integral over the vector $\vec{x}$?) Does it refer to the line integral of any curve between the two points, or something completely different?

Comment: This is line integral. Just path where the work had done, it can be curve or straight line.

Answer (score 0):

Work is a scalar, not a vector. The dot product $\vec F \cdot \vec dx$ is a scalar, so the integral is over a scalar, not a vector. $\vec F \cdot \vec dx$ is the work done by the force moving the body a differential distance.  The total work is the integral over the path travelled by the body, starting at $x_1$ and ending at $x_2$.  The limits on the integral merely specify the coordinates of the initial point and the final point; you cannot evaluate the integral until you know the path taken between the initial and final points (similar such integrals dependent on the path occur in thermodynamics).

The work can also be expressed as $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec F \cdot \vec v \enspace dt$, since $d \vec x = \vec v \enspace dt$, where $t$ is time and $\vec v$ is velocity.

All of this is true whether or not the force is conservative.  If the force is conservative, the work is independent of the path taken between the initial and final end points, and a potential energy can be defined and used in place of work, as discussed in the Wikipedia article you reference.  An advantage of using potential energy is no matter how complex the path from the initial to the final position, the work is simply the negative of the change in potential energy.

See a good basic physics text for the definition of work in mechanics, such as one of the Halliday and Resnick texts.

Here we are using the mechanics concept of work, defined as the change in kinetic energy.  Work as used in thermodynamics is a much broader concept; see my answer to  [Positive and negative Work, question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/678280/positive-and-negative-work-question) on this exchange.